# Exception in Tkinter callback, KeyError: 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 351, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: 0 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-18-518ef7ebbd84>", line 4, in myClick2
    a.plot(p1.total_payoff()[0],p1.total_payoff()[1])
  File "<ipython-input-10-57724152e4a6>", line 59, in total_payoff
    prices = self.option_payoff()[0]
  File "<ipython-input-10-57724152e4a6>", line 47, in option_payoff
    temppayoff += callpayoff(i,j.get_strike(),j.find_bidask()[1])*j.get_quantity()
  File "<ipython-input-6-59b6ad5c0680>", line 28, in find_bidask
    bid = data['bid'][0]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 353, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

This is the error message I am getting when I try to execute a function by clicking a TKinter button. The function is below, basically it takes some data (x, y), and plots it with matplotlib.

```
def myClick2():
    f = Figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot(p1.total_payoff()[0],p1.total_payoff()[1])
    a.grid(True, which='both')
    a.axhline(y=0, color='k')
    a.axvline(x=0, color='k')
    
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 8, column = 1)
```

The error is saying that "total_payoff", which calls "option_payoff", which calls "find_bidask" is leading to the error. Specifically, the part which I assign bid = data['bid'][0].

```
    def find_bidask(self):
        if str.upper(self.cp) == 'C':
            data = self.data['calls']
        else:
            data = self.data['puts']
        data = data[data['contractSymbol']==self.symbol].reset_index(drop=True)
        bid = data['bid'][0]
        ask = data['ask'][0]
```

However, when I run this separately outside of TKinter, it produces no error, and ['bid'][0] is available as a value. I don't understand what is wrong with my code - is it something in the tkinter myclick2 function that is wrong?

Comment: Make sure the button has `command = myClick2` and not `command = myClick2()` otherwise the code will run when the button is created, which is probably what causes your error.

Comment: I had this:
myButton2 = Button(root, text="Draw", command = myClick2)
so i don't think that's the issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: error shows problem in line `bid = data['bid'][0]` in function `find_bidask`. It may suggest that `data['bid']` is empty so you can't get `[0]`. First use `print()` to see what you have in variables inside function. Maybe you changed something in data and now it has something different then you expect.

Comment: what is `self.symbol`? Maybe it has different value than you expect and it select empty `data`. We can't run your code, we can't see your data - so you have to test it on your own.